# Typescript TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type

Tags: typescript

I experienced an error in the following example.

I'm worried about how I can solve it.

I'd appreciate your help.

```js
type TestValue = {
  value: string;
};

type FirstTest = {
  type: 'text';
  text: TestValue[];
};

type SecondTest = {
  type: 'heading';
  heading: TestValue;
};

type Test = FirstTest | SecondTest;

const firstTest: Test = {
  type: 'text',
  text: [
    {
      value: 'Text!!',
    },
  ],
};
const secondTest: Test = {
  type: 'heading',
  heading: {
    value: 'heading!!',
  },
};

const foo = (data: Test) => {
  const { type } = data;

  const content = data[type]; //Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"text" | "heading"' can't be used to index type 'Test'.   Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Test'.

  switch (type) {
    case 'heading':
      return content.value;
    case 'text':
      return content[0].value;
  }
};
```

However, I get the error `TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"text" | "heading"' can't be used to index type 'Test'.   Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Test`

Running in a foo function results in a type error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to benefit from the discriminated union type, you need to only attempt to access `data[type]` within the block in which `type` was discriminated, i.e. in this case from within your `switch` statement:

```
const foo = (data: Test) => {
  const { type } = data;
  let content: FirstTest['text'] | SecondTest['heading']

  type // "text" | "heading"
  data // FirstTest | SecondTest
  data[type] // invalid as neither "text" nor "heading" appear on both FirstTest and SecondTest

  switch (type) {
    case 'heading':
      type // "heading"
      data // SecondTest
      content = data[type] // valid as SecondTest['heading'] exists
      return content.value;
    case 'text':
      type // "text"
      data // FirstTest
      content = data[type] // valid as FirstTest['text'] exists
      return content[0].value;
  }
};
```

In practice you can just avoid creating the `content` variable altogether:

```
const foo = (data: Test) => {
  const { type } = data;

  switch (type) {
    case 'heading':
      return data[type].value; // valid
    case 'text':
      return data[type][0].value; // valid
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I learned a lot from your answers.